# Where i am going wrong in solving the inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

If $\cos x \left(\cos x+\frac12\right) >0$ then where should $x$ lie in the interval $(0,\pi)$

**What I tried**

When i made two cases i got correct answer but when i used **wavy-curve method**. I am not getting the correct answer.

Can anyone please use wavy curve to show where $x$ lies for that inequality to be true

Comment: When is $\cos x = 0$, for $x\in (0,\pi)$? When is $\cos x = -{1\over2}$, for $x\in (0,\pi)$?

Comment: What is the "wavy-curve method?"

Comment: @Dr.MV It's basically just figuring out where the factors change sign in an inequality of the form $f(x)g(x) > 0$, in order to find the intervals on which both factors have the same sign. Seems to be an Indian Institute Of Technology term judging by the Google results.

Comment: It's called that because you draw a wavy curve while solving the inequality; see http://kushagrabasti.blogspot.com/2012/06/wavy-curve-method-wavy-curve-method-is.html for an example.

Comment: The "wavy-curve" is just a visualization "shorthand" for what you did with your cases anyway.  The product of the factors is positive where both $ \ \cos x \ $ is positive (first quadrant) and $ \ \cos x \ > \ -\frac{1}{2} \ $ (automatically satisfied in first quadrant) , or both $ \ \cos x \ $ is _negative_ (second quadrant) and $ \ \cos x \ < \ -\frac{1}{2} \ $ (which occurs for...?).

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-Go to $\frac x2$ and $\tan \frac x2=t$. You have $\cos x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $$ \cos x \left(\cos x+\frac12\right) >0\iff \frac{(3+t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}\cdot (1+t)(1-t)>0$$
Now $\tan \frac x2<1\Rightarrow 0<\frac x2<\frac{\pi}{4}$. It follows what?